# SQL Server - Group last paid price by customer and product code

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will do the following.

I have a table with separate sales order lines on it. Each line details the customer, product sold, the price sold at, and the date of the sale.

I am trying to establish for each product code, what the last price we sold it for was for each separate customer.

For example using my input below I would expect Product code ABC to return '10' for Brian, '20' for Gary, and '50 for Sam.

Below is complete set of results I would expect for all product codes.

Input

```
Order No    Customer    Product Code    Price   Date
-----------------------------------------------------------
1           Brian        ABC            10      12/04/2018
2           Brian        ABC            14      01/04/2018
3           Gary         ABC            20      12/04/2018
4           Gary         ABC            35      12/04/2017
5           Sam          ABD            40      06/08/2017
6           Sam          ABC            50      20/08/2017
7           Adam         ABE            20      15/06/2016
8           Adam         ABE            30      17/03/2017
```

Output

```
Order No    Customer    Product Code    Price   Date 1  Brian ABC   10  12/04/2018 3    Gary    ABC 20  12/04/2018 6    Sam ABC 50  20/08/2017 5    Sam ABD 40  06/08/2017 8    Adam ABE    30  17/03/2017
```

Comment: can you post what have you tried?

Comment: After formatting your result sets, I can see no different between the two... Is this an error on your part, or am I missing something?

Comment: row_number() will be in your solution.

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Answer (score 1):

You can you `Row_number()` with `partition BY [product code], [customer]`  for this.

Following query should work for you scenario

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT [order no], 
               [customer], 
               [product code], 
               [price], 
               [date], 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY [product code], [customer] 
                   ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS RN 
        FROM   [table]) T 
WHERE  T.rn = 1
```

Comment: @Pரதீப், I feel ORDER BY [Date] DESC should give the last price

Answer (score 0):

This is all about the row_number():

Allows you to partition (Similar to group) and provide an order

```
select top 1 with ties *
from table
order by  row_number() over (partition by [Product Code],Customer order by date desc)
```

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong out put. Here is what it should be Order No Customer Product Code Price Date
1 Brian ABC 10 12/04/2018
3 Gary ABC 20 12/04/2018
6 Sam ABC 50 20/08/2017
5 Sam ABD 40 06/08/2017
8 Adam ABE 30 17/03/2017

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select a.* from #temp a join (
select customer,  [product code], max(Date) maxdate
from #temp
group by customer, [product code])b
on a.customer=b.customer and a.date=b.maxdate and a.[product code]=b.[product code]
```

Comment: Can anyone help now I've amended my output results. Sorry about that

Comment: please post in the original output spot on top of page

Comment: look at my code above - it works i just tested it against your new expected output

Comment: could you advise on which bits of the code I am supposed to replace with my relevent info? i.e Should #temp me my table name?